# Accessing elements of nested hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

I'm working a little utility written in ruby that makes extensive use of nested hashes.  Currently, I'm checking access to nested hash elements as follows:

```
structure = { :a => { :b => 'foo' }}

# I want structure[:a][:b]

value = nil

if structure.has_key?(:a) && structure[:a].has_key?(:b) then
  value = structure[:a][:b]
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I'd like to be able to say:

```
value = structure[:a][:b]
```

And get `nil` if :a is not a key in `structure`, etc.

Comment: Ruby 2.3 added `Hash#dig` to solve exactly this problem. See my answer below.

Comment: There should be an SO badge for marking a five year old question as a duplicate, and another for having a five-year old question tagged as such.  Achievement unlocked!

Comment: If you are using a Ruby before 2.3, (structure[:a] || {})[:b] should should do the trick

Comment: Instead of using`Hash#dig`, I will go idiomatic with @PaulMorie answer, and use the safe navigation operator `.&` — like in `h&.fetch(:a,nil).&fetch(:b,nil)`, navigating blindly through nested hashes or mixed structures which can have not existing (nil) intermediate keys. This kind of structures should be avoided anyway.  Both `dig` and `.&` methods were introduced in Ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The way I usually do this these days is:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
```

This will give you a hash that creates a new hash as the entry for a missing key, but returns nil for the second level of key:

```
h['foo'] -> {}
h['foo']['bar'] -> nil
```

You can nest this to add multiple layers that can be addressed this way:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |hh, kk| hh[kk] = {} } }

h['bar'] -> {}
h['tar']['zar'] -> {}
h['scar']['far']['mar'] -> nil
```

You can also chain indefinitely by using the `default_proc` method:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

h['bar'] -> {}
h['tar']['star']['par'] -> {}
```

The above code creates a hash whose default proc creates a new Hash with the same default proc.  So, a hash created as a default value when a lookup for an unseen key occurs will have the same default behavior.

**EDIT: More details**

Ruby hashes allow you to control how default values are created when a lookup occurs for a new key.  When specified, this behavior is encapsulated as a `Proc` object and is reachable via the [`default_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) and [`default_proc=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) methods.  The default proc can also be specified by passing a block to [`Hash.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Let's break this code down a little.  This is not idiomatic ruby, but it's easier to break it out into multiple lines:

```
1. recursive_hash = Hash.new do |h, k|
2.   h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)
3. end
```

Line 1 declares a variable `recursive_hash` to be a new `Hash` and begins a block to be `recursive_hash`'s `default_proc`.  The block is passed two objects: `h`, which is the `Hash` instance the key lookup is being performed on, and `k`, the key being looked up.

Line 2 sets the default value in the hash to a new `Hash` instance.  The default behavior for this hash is supplied by passing a `Proc` created from the `default_proc` of the hash the lookup is occurring in; ie, the default proc the block itself is defining.

Here's an example from an IRB session:

```
irb(main):011:0> recursive_hash = Hash.new do |h,k|
irb(main):012:1* h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)
irb(main):013:1> end
=> {}
irb(main):014:0> recursive_hash[:foo]
=> {}
irb(main):015:0> recursive_hash
=> {:foo=>{}}
```

When the hash at `recursive_hash[:foo]` was created, its `default_proc` was supplied by `recursive_hash`'s `default_proc`.  This has two effects:

1. The default behavior for `recursive_hash[:foo]` is the same as `recursive_hash`.
2. The default behavior for hashes created by `recursive_hash[:foo]`'s `default_proc` will be the same as `recursive_hash`.

So, continuing in IRB, we get the following:

```
irb(main):016:0> recursive_hash[:foo][:bar]
=> {}
irb(main):017:0> recursive_hash
=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{}}}
irb(main):018:0> recursive_hash[:foo][:bar][:zap]
=> {}
irb(main):019:0> recursive_hash
=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{:zap=>{}}}}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, can you help me understand how the last one works? I posted a separate question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20158213/273333 Thanks!

Comment: @mdm414ZX I've edited my answer to provide more details.  Hope that helps.

Comment: For noobs like myself that want to use this but don't know how to have a default value for the sub-hashes, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30037418/3399416). Don't trip on the same stone...

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0 added `Hash#dig` to solve this problem. See my answer.

Comment: Nice, much better than my `h = eval("Hash.new { |v| v || " * 21 + " Hash.new { } " + "} "  * 21)`

Comment: If you want a counter, you can do `h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }`

Comment: @ user513951 this answer, not yours, is the idiomatic way to use nested hashes in Ruby. You only need dig when navigating blindly through nested hashes or mixed structures which can have not existing (nil) intermediate keys. This can be overcome starting from Ruby 2.3.0 combining the safe navigation operator (.&) and fetch(…,nil) — like in `h&.fetch(:a,nil).&fetch(:b,nil)`
@CarySwoveland no, this is wrong. Learn how Proc works in the details of this answer.

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani, I was just a kid when I wrote that so many years ago...

Answer (score 68):

Traditionally, you really had to do something like this:

```
structure[:a] && structure[:a][:b]
```

However, Ruby 2.3 added a method [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) that makes this way more graceful:

```
structure.dig :a, :b # nil if it misses anywhere along the way
```

There is a gem called [`ruby_dig`](https://github.com/mottalrd/hash_dig_and_collect/) that will back-patch this for you.

Comment: I think you should remove the bit about the top-level hash, since this won't apply arbitrarily deep, so `h[:foo][:bar][:jim]` will still blow up.

Comment: Another gotcha with the default hash value is that it is not persistable.  If you dump your data structure to disk and load it later it will loose it's default state, same thing if you send it over the wire.  Unlike other classes that explicitly raise errors when this happens Marshal.dump(Hash.new(foo)) will succeed happily loosing your default value.

Comment: Aren't you introducing a bit of reference problem with `Hash.new({})`? Won't every default entry end up using the same hash?

Comment: Yes, every default will use the same empty hash, but that's OK. `h[:new_key] = new_value` will create a new entry, and won't modify the default value.

Comment: But if you start doing things like `h = Hash.new({}); h[:a][:b] = 1; h[:c][:d] = 2` you're in for a mess of confusion.

Comment: That would be bad, si. It gives you multi-level reads but takes away multi-level writes in most cases. It's perhaps a bit too dangerous as a general idea.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Josh FYI the reason it is not is that  this answer was edited to add the correct answer at a much later date

Answer (score 48):

`Hash` and `Array` have a [method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig).

```
value = structure.dig(:a, :b)
```

It returns `nil` if the key is missing at any level.

---

If you are using a version of Ruby older than 2.3, you can install a gem such as `ruby_dig` or `hash_dig_and_collect`, or implement this functionality yourself:

```
module RubyDig
  def dig(key, *rest)
    if value = (self[key] rescue nil)
      if rest.empty?
        value
      elsif value.respond_to?(:dig)
        value.dig(*rest)
      end
    end
  end
end

if RUBY_VERSION < '2.3'
  Array.send(:include, RubyDig)
  Hash.send(:include, RubyDig)
end
```

Answer (score 14):

I made rubygem for this. Try [vine](https://github.com/guangnan/vine).

Install:

```
gem install vine
```

Usage:

```
hash.access("a.b.c")
```

Comment: Fantastic, I'm calling SharePoint web services using Savon (which is great) and my response is the following using Vine... ;-)  data.vine("get_user_collection_from_group_response.get_user_collection_from_group_result.get_user_collection_from_group.users.user")

Comment: Vine seems interesting, but you may also want to check out Hashie, which is a more complete library. See my answer.

Comment: As an aside this really is only good for accessing elements in the hash. Don't expect to be able to replace the values using this method.

Answer (score 7):

I think one of the most readable solutions is using [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie):

```
require 'hashie'
myhash = Hashie::Mash.new({foo: {bar: "blah" }})

myhash.foo.bar
=> "blah"    

myhash.foo?
=> true

# use "underscore dot" for multi-level testing
myhash.foo_.bar?
=> true
myhash.foo_.huh_.what?
=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
value = structure[:a][:b] rescue nil
```

Comment: This will silently turn missing variables or methods, among other things, into nil.  In a way that's the intent, but this is a broad knife for what perhaps should be a fine cut.

Comment: I'm very cautious about using `rescue` like that, much for the same reason that Wayne gives, but also because it can mask errors in logic or syntax that you should know about. Finding errors masked this way can be tough.

Answer (score 2):

You could just build a Hash subclass with an extra variadic method for digging all the way down with appropriate checks along the way. Something like this (with a better name of course):

```
class Thing < Hash
  def find(*path)
    path.inject(self) { |h, x| return nil if(!h.is_a?(Thing) || h[x].nil?); h[x] }
  end
end
```

Then just use `Thing`s instead of hashes:

```
>> x = Thing.new
=> {}
>> x[:a] = Thing.new
=> {}
>> x[:a][:b] = 'k'
=> "k"
>> x.find(:a)
=> {:b=>"k"}
>> x.find(:a, :b)
=> "k"
>> x.find(:a, :b, :c)
=> nil
>> x.find(:a, :c, :d)
=> nil
```

Comment: Why don't you get a local jump error from that return? Your code definitely works. I would think this is roughly equivalent: >> hash = {:a => {:b => 'k'}} >> [:a, :b].inject(hash) {|h, x| return nil if (h[x].nil? || !h[x].is_a?(Hash)); h[x] }, but gives a LocalJumpError

Comment: @rainkinz: You're getting a LocalJumpError because your block is trying to return without being inside a method (or "a method which declared the block" to be pedantic). My `return` works because it is returning from the `find` method, your version doesn't have anywhere to return from so Ruby throws a hissy fit.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

I suggested this in my question before:

```
class NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end
```

`Hash#to_hash` is already defined, and returns self. Then you can do:

```
value = structure[:a].to_hash[:b]
```

The `to_hash` ensures that you get an empty hash when the previous key search fails.

**Solution2**

This solution is similar in spirit to mu is too short's answer in that it uses a subclass, but still somewhat different. In case there is no value for a certain key, it does not use a default value, but rather creates a value of empty hash, so that it does not have the problem of confusion in assigment that DigitalRoss's answer has, as was pointed out by mu is too short.

```
class NilFreeHash < Hash
  def [] key; key?(key) ? super(key) : self[key] = NilFreeHash.new end
end

structure = NilFreeHash.new
structure[:a][:b] = 3
p strucrture[:a][:b] # => 3
```

It departs from the specification given in the question, though. When an undefined key is given, it will return an empty hash instread of `nil`.

```
p structure[:c] # => {}
```

If you build an instance of this NilFreeHash from the beginning and assign the key-values, it will work, but if you want to convert a hash into an instance of this class, that may be a problem.

Comment: Why not combine both your answers into one?

Comment: They are unrelated, and I though it's better for them to be separated. Are you suggesting to put two solutions in one post, or combining them to give a different answer?

Comment: Put them both in one answer. That's a very common practice on SO, especially when you compare/contrast them.

Comment: Cool. *I* find it nice that way because it's a lot easier to see the differences in the approaches. That's a lot harder when they're separate answers.

Comment: I see. I guess I am still learning know about the custom here.

Answer (score 1):

The XKeys gem will read and auto-vivify-on-write nested hashes (::Hash) or hashes and arrays (::Auto, based on the key/index type) with a simple, clear, readable, and compact syntax by enhancing #[] and #[]=. The sentinel symbol :[] will push onto the end of an array.

```
require 'xkeys'

structure = {}.extend XKeys::Hash
structure[:a, :b] # nil
structure[:a, :b, :else => 0] # 0 (contextual default)
structure[:a] # nil, even after above
structure[:a, :b] = 'foo'
structure[:a, :b] # foo
```

Comment: For those interested, here is the source code of `xkeys`: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/d5330b42473f15c1019b26dd3519eaca

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/xkeys/

Answer (score 1):

This monkey patch function for Hash should be easiest (at least for me). It also doesn't alter structure i.e. changing `nil`'s to `{}`. It would still also apply even if you're reading a tree from a raw source e.g. JSON. It also doesn't need to produce empty hash objects as it goes or parse a string. `rescue nil` was actually a good easy solution for me as I'm brave enough for such a low risk but I find it to essentially have a drawback with performance.

```
class ::Hash
  def recurse(*keys)
    v = self[keys.shift]
    while keys.length > 0
      return nil if not v.is_a? Hash
      v = v[keys.shift]
    end
    v
  end
end
```

Example:

```
> structure = { :a => { :b => 'foo' }}
=> {:a=>{:b=>"foo"}}

> structure.recurse(:a, :b)
=> "foo"

> structure.recurse(:a, :x)
=> nil
```

What's also good is that you can play around saved arrays with it:

```
> keys = [:a, :b]
=> [:a, :b]

> structure.recurse(*keys)
=> "foo"

> structure.recurse(*keys, :x1, :x2)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem, but I'm becoming more and more wary of it:

```
>> structure = { :a => { :b => 'foo' }} #=> {:a=>{:b=>"foo"}}
>> require 'andand' #=> true
>> structure[:a].andand[:b] #=> "foo"
>> structure[:c].andand[:b] #=> nil
```

Comment: Michael, Is the reason for your wariness worth mentioning?

Comment: @Wayne: I've found that spurious use of `andand` in our app sometimes covers a problem that could have been found easily for too long.

Answer (score 0):

There is the cute but wrong way to do this.  Which is to monkey-patch `NilClass` to add a `[]` method that returns `nil`.  I say it is the wrong approach because you have no idea what other software may have made a different version, or what behavior change in a future version of Ruby can be broken by this.

A better approach is to create a new object that works a lot like `nil` but supports this behavior.  Make this new object the default return of your hashes.  And then it will just work.

Alternately you can create a simple "nested lookup" function that you pass the hash and the keys to, which traverses the hashes in order, breaking out when it can.

I would personally prefer one of the latter two approaches.  Though I think it would be cute if the first was integrated into the Ruby language.  (But monkey-patching is a bad idea.  Don't do that.  Particularly not to demonstrate what a cool hacker you are.)

Comment: Aww, I've never been called cute before. :) I do agree that this is convenient but ultimately too dangerous to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would do it, but you can Monkeypatch in `NilClass#[]`:

```
> structure = { :a => { :b => 'foo' }}
#=> {:a=>{:b=>"foo"}}

> structure[:x][:y]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

> class NilClass; def [](*a); end; end
#=> nil

> structure[:x][:y]
#=> nil

> structure[:a][:y]
#=> nil

> structure[:a][:b]
#=> "foo"
```

Go with @DigitalRoss's answer. Yes, it's more typing, but that's because it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed a two-dimensional matrix where each cell is a list of items.

I found this technique which seems to work. It might work for the OP:

```
$all = Hash.new()

def $all.[](k)
  v = fetch(k, nil)
  return v if v

  h = Hash.new()
  def h.[](k2)
    v = fetch(k2, nil)
    return v if v
    list = Array.new()
    store(k2, list)
    return list
  end

  store(k, h)
  return h
end

$all['g1-a']['g2-a'] << '1'
$all['g1-a']['g2-a'] << '2'

$all['g1-a']['g2-a'] << '3'
$all['g1-a']['g2-b'] << '4'

$all['g1-b']['g2-a'] << '5'
$all['g1-b']['g2-c'] << '6'

$all.keys.each do |group1|
  $all[group1].keys.each do |group2|
    $all[group1][group2].each do |item|
      puts "#{group1} #{group2} #{item}"
    end
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
$ ruby -v && ruby t.rb
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
g1-a g2-a 1
g1-a g2-a 2
g1-a g2-a 3
g1-a g2-b 4
g1-b g2-a 5
g1-b g2-c 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying out this:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# System so that we chain methods together without worrying about nil
# values (a la Objective-c).
# Example:
#   params[:foo].try?[:bar]
#
class Object
  # Returns self, unless NilClass (see below)
  def try?
    self
  end
end  
class NilClass
  class MethodMissingSink
    include Singleton
    def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    end
  end
  def try?
    MethodMissingSink.instance
  end
end
```

I know the arguments against `try`, but it is useful when looking into things, like say, `params`.