# access elements in Ruby nested hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access the elements in a nested hash where keys are similar symbols.

```
favs = { 
  :art => "painters",
  :survey1 => [ 
    {:name => "Josh", :painter => "Dali" },
    {:name => "Mona", :painter => "Monet"}
  ],
  :survey2 => [ 
    {:name => "Leon", :answer => "None"},
    {:name => "Port", :answer => "Picasso"},
  ]
}
```

Q1: Delete Leon-

I came up with this:

```
favs[:survey2].each { |hash|
hash.delete_if { |k,v| 
v=="Leon"
}
}
```

but I couldn't figure out how to tie the second key value pair in (the answer/painter) after removing just the name.

Q2 Return Josh's favorite painter - same problem, I can find :name=>Josh but not sure how to return corresponding painter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My answer via a question would be, why are you using a nested hash? Create an object instead, primitives are just that, primitive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of nested hashes in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544858/accessing-elements-of-nested-hashes-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1:

You must delete Hash's in Array, not elements in Hash.

```
favs[:survey2].delete_if {|i| i[:name] == "Leon"}
```

A2:

```
favs[:survey1].find { |i| i[:name] == "Josh" }[:painter]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I mention in the comments, don't use primitive when they become too, erm, primitive. Nested anythings are a hint you're at that stage:

```
class Student
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :favourite_painter

  def initialize( name, opts={} )
    @name = name
    @favourite_painter = opts[:favourite_painter]
  end
end

students = []
students << Student.new( "Josh", :favourite_painter => "Dali" )
students << Student.new( "Mona", :favourite_painter => "Monet" )
# etc…
```

And see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html.

Comment: It is an exercise and those are the problems I need to solve. I didn't make up the hash itself. 
In your answer I am not sure what the Student refers to.

Comment: What you've posted appears to be a list of students (or people) and their favourite painter. Josh is a student, and his favourite painter is Dali. Student is a class created to hold the data, as to put data in a nested hash is, as I said before, making life difficult for yourself. I'm not sure what the _aim_ of the exercise is, is it to learn to recurse through a structure you probably wouldn't come across because you wouldn't create one like that, or is it to learn Ruby? This is exactly why Ruby has classes baked in, unlike Perl, to make stuff like this easier.