# Ruby Hash: creating a default value for non-existing elements

Tags: ruby, hash

I learned from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17356513/273333) that this is possible:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

h['bar'] # => {}
h['tar']['star']['par'] # => {}
```

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: Do you know how [`Hash#default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) works?

Comment: This is confusing enough that I edited it to reflect what I assume you intended. Note that `-> {}` is a `lambda` function, which is the main source of the confusion in what you showed previously.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I just copied the code from the original answer.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the reference. I understand it better now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hashes have a thing called a [`default_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc), which is simply a proc that Ruby runs when you try to access a hash key that doesn't exist. This proc receives both the hash itself and the target key as parameters.

You can set a Hash's `default_proc` at any time. Passing a block parameter to `Hash.new` simply allows you to initialize a Hash and set its `default_proc` in one step:

```
h = Hash.new
h.default_proc = proc{ |hash, key| hash[key] = 'foo' }

# The above is equivalent to:

h = Hash.new{ |hash, key| hash[key] = 'foo' }
```

We can also access the default proc for a hash by calling `h.default_proc`. Knowing this, and knowing that the ampersand (`&`) allows a proc passed as a normal parameter to be treated as a block parameter, we can now explain how this code works:

```
cool_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

The block passed to `Hash.new` will be called when we try to access a key that doesn't exist. This block will receive the hash itself as `h`, and the key we tried to access as `k`. We respond by setting `h[k]` (that is, the value of the key we're trying to access) to a new hash. Into the constructor of this new hash, we pass the "parent" hash's `default_proc`, using an ampersand to force it to be interpreted as a block parameter. This is the equivalent of doing the following, to an infinite depth:

```
cool_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new{ ... } } }
```

The end result is that the key we tried to access was initialized to a new Hash, which itself will initialize any "not found" keys to a new Hash, which itself will have the same behavior, etc. [It's hashes all the way down.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

Comment: Very clear explanation, Grantovich.  One detail: doesn't `h.default_proc` return a block, and the `&` converts it to a proc?

Comment: `h.default_proc` returns a proc, as the name suggests. Blocks literally *are* procs, so there's no conversion being done per se; "block" is just a name for the proc that gets called when we `yield`, and can be passed to any method using the "block syntax". When we want to pass a block non-literally, we have to use `&` to tell Ruby "treat this proc as though I had passed it using the block syntax". [This blog post may demystify things further.](http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/)

Answer (score 1):

In this code you create hashes by chain, so that any link of chain would have same `default_proc`

So, `default_proc` of `h` and `h['bar']` and so far will be the same - it will return new instance of `Hash` with this `default_proc`