# In Ruby, how to set a default value for a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

I recently looked for a way to correctly create and use nested hashes in Ruby. I promptly found a [solution by Paul Morie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17356513/3399416), who answered his own question:

`hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }`

I promptly went to use this and am glad to report it works. However, as the title says, I'd like *the "secondary", "inside" hashes to **return 0** by default*.

I'm aware that you can define the default return value of a hash both in its constructor ("`Hash.new(0)`") or using `.default` ("`hash.default(0)`").

But how would you do this with hashes inside a hash?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently I only had to do:

`hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }`

Whoops. I'll try not to be so hasty to ask a question next time.