# Ruby way to query over a json object

Tags: ruby

I have the following json string:

```
[{"name": "John", "room": "A"},
 {"name": "Nick", "room": "A"},
 {"name": "Bill", "room": "B"}]
```

How can I extract the records whose "`room"` value equals `"A"` without iterating over all of them explicitly?

I'm looking for a simple way to search over elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of nested hashes in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544858/accessing-elements-of-nested-hashes-in-ruby)

Comment: Define "iterating explicitly".

Comment: @paulo : Please post your expected output as well

Comment: I mean a "each" block over the object.

Comment: @paulo : then check my answer it is suitable for your requirement. Also check the reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)**

```
> array.select{|a| a[:room] == "A"}
#=> [{:name=>"John", :room=>"A"}, {:name=>"Nick", :room=>"A"}]
```

Comment: I am not sure whether OP wanted to avoid this.

Comment: @sawa : Why? Is OP expected anything else

Comment: The OP wrote they wanted to avoid explicitly iterating over. It is not clear what that means, but your answer may be such case.

Comment: @sawa : yes you are right. Even I m also confused with that but I assume generally he want this only. If OP make clear so I can modify my answer as per his requirement.

Comment: So, since there's no explicit `.each` in the code above, this does qualify per OP's definition. While it does (internally) iterate through, doing otherwise is practically impossible :}

Comment: @D-side but it's **iterate** over an array.

Comment: @D-side : Is there any other best way then love to see as post.

Comment: @GaganGami I believe yours is *the one*. The array structure implies this can't be done more efficiently anyway. If that were something else, there would be room for thought.