# Initialising a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a hash of hashes as follows:

```
order_history = {}

order_history[customer_id][order_id] = { :total_spend => order_spend, :date => order_date }
```

When I add entries into this hash I have to check whether the customer_id exists first, like so:

```
order_history[customer_id] = {} unless order_history.has_key?(customer_id)
```

Then, I can add the details for an individual order:

```
order_history[123][456] = { :total_spend => 200.45, :date => 2016-05-03 }
```

Is it possible to declare the order_history hash as a hash-of-hashes at the outset, so I don't have to do the test every time? Or is there a way of telling ruby that when a new key is created, set the value to be a new, empty hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this for your hash :

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

h['bar'] -> {}
h['tar']['star']['par'] -> {}
```

For more information, this answer is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544858/accessing-elements-of-nested-hashes-in-ruby/17356513#17356513)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by @XavM perfectly answers the question, I would drop here a reference to excellent [`Hashie#Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash). Using the latter, one might do for string keys:

```
▶ require 'hashie/mash'
▶ hm = Hashie::Mash.new
#⇒ {}
▶ hm.foo.bar
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for nil:NilClass
```

but:

```
▶ hm.foo!.bar
#⇒ nil
▶ hm.foo!.bar!
#⇒ {}
```

Sometimes it is more handy, than defining a `default_proc`.

**NB** the correct answer to the question stated in OP is provided by @XavM, please upvote it. I just dropped it here as an addendum.