# Can't loop through JSON data because of the error "no implicit conversion of hash into integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello and good afternoon all!

I am getting an error in my console that states "TypeError: No implicit conversion of hash into integer" and I know that it is referring to my loop in my Ruby class document.

Here is my Ruby file:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'pp'
require 'pry'

=begin
find a way to access the latitude and longitude of the nearest charging station globally
find a way to access the latitude and longitude of the user
create a function that finds the nearest station based on accepting both sets of coordinates and finds the difference
=end

class ChargingStations
    include HTTParty
    attr_accessor :pois
    puts "loading"
    @@latitude = ''

    base_uri 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v2'

    def self.puts_latitude
        puts @@latitude
    end

    def initialize(pois)
        @@pois = pois
        @@latitude = @@pois
        puts @@pois
    end

    def self.put_value
      puts @@latitude
    end

    def self.find_sites
      for i in @@pois do
          puts @@pois[i]
          if @@pois[i]["AddressInfo"]["StateOrProvince"] == "New York"
              puts @@pois[i]
              end
          end
      end

    def self.generate
        response = get('/poi')
        puts "got here"

        if response.success?
            puts "success"
            self.new(response)


        else
            puts "failure"
            raise response.response
        end
    end
end

binding.pry
```

If you are able to answer the question, please explain why my loop does not work for myself and future developers.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems kind of hard to say anything helpful without seeing the data structure. Also, that `for i in @@pois` is pretty non-Ruby. Something like `@@pois.each do |poi|` would be more idiomatic. TBH, I'm not even sure if that's valid syntax. (It might be.) That may well be your problem.

Comment: @jvillian you might be onto something. I tried to use what I have learned thus far but the syntax may be completely off

Comment: Your error reminds the problem of accessing nested hashes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5544858/4906586. Following @jvillian comment, a `@@pois.each do |poi| ... end` would be more Ruby-ish and less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give this a try:

```
class ChargingStations
  include HTTParty

  @@latitude = ''

  base_uri 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v2'

  class << self

    def pois
      @@pois 
    end

    def puts_latitude
      puts @@latitude
    end

    def put_value
      puts @@latitude
    end

    def state_or_provinces
      @state_or_provinces ||= @@pois.map do |poi|
        poi.try(:[],'AddressInfo').try(:[],'StateOrProvince')
      end.uniq
    end

    def find_sites(state_or_province=nil)
      @state_or_province = state_or_province
      @state_or_province ||= 'New York'
      @@pois.select do |poi|
        poi.try(:[],'AddressInfo').try(:[],'StateOrProvince') == @state_or_province
      end
    end

    def generate
      response = get('/poi')
      if response.success?
        @@pois = response.parsed_response
        @@latitude = @@pois
        return true
      else
        puts "failure"
        raise response.response
      end
    end

  end # Class methods

end
```

Then, in console, I get:

```
ChargingStations.generate
 => true

ChargingStations.find_sites.count
 => 2

ChargingStations.find_sites.first
 => {"ID"=>112491, "UUID"=>"5EA5B030-AFEF-4CFA-88DF-3A9F6CFFDAB5", "ParentChargePointID"=>nil, "DataProviderID"=>1, "DataProvider"=>{"WebsiteURL"=>"http://openchargemap.org", "Comments"=>nil, "DataProviderStatusType"=>{"IsProviderEnabled"=>true, "ID"=>1, "Title"=>"Manual Data Entry"}, "IsRestrictedEdit"=>false, "IsOpenDataLicensed"=>true, "IsApprovedImport"=>true, "License"=>"Licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-SA 4.0)", "DateLastImported"=>nil, "ID"=>1, "Title"=>"Open Charge Map Contributors"}, "DataProvidersReference"=>nil, "OperatorID"=>5, "OperatorInfo"=>{"WebsiteURL"=>"http://www.chargepoint.net/", "Comments"=>nil, "PhonePrimaryContact"=>"1-888-758-4389", "PhoneSecondaryContact"=>nil, "IsPrivateIndividual"=>false, "AddressInfo"=>nil, "BookingURL"=>nil, "ContactEmail"=>"support@coulombtech.com", "FaultReportEmail"=>"support@coulombtech.com", "IsRestrictedEdit"=>nil, "ID"=>5, "Title"=>"ChargePoint (Coulomb Technologies)"}, "OperatorsReference"=>nil, "UsageTypeID"=>1, "UsageType"=>{"IsPayAtLocation"=>nil, "IsMembershipRequired"=>nil, "IsAccessKeyRequired"=>nil, "ID"=>1, "Title"=>"Public"}, "UsageCost"=>"free", "AddressInfo"=>{"ID"=>112837, "Title"=>"1 Locks Plaza", "AddressLine1"=>"1 Locks Plaza", "AddressLine2"=>nil, "Town"=>"Lockport", "StateOrProvince"=>"New York", "Postcode"=>"14094", "CountryID"=>2, "Country"=>{"ISOCode"=>"US", "ContinentCode"=>"NA", "ID"=>2, "Title"=>"United States"}, "Latitude"=>43.169316400362, "Longitude"=>-78.6954369797903, "ContactTelephone1"=>nil, "ContactTelephone2"=>nil, "ContactEmail"=>nil, "AccessComments"=>"Located at the Lockport Municipal building, \"The Big Bridge\" and the \"Flight of Five\" locks 34 and 35 on the Erie Canal.", "RelatedURL"=>nil, "Distance"=>nil, "DistanceUnit"=>0}, "NumberOfPoints"=>1, "GeneralComments"=>"Located at the \"Big Bridge\" and \"Flight of Five\" locks 34 and 35 and the Lockport Municipal building", "DatePlanned"=>nil, "DateLastConfirmed"=>nil, "StatusTypeID"=>50, "StatusType"=>{"IsOperational"=>true, "IsUserSelectable"=>true, "ID"=>50, "Title"=>"Operational"}, "DateLastStatusUpdate"=>"2018-11-04T12:56:00Z", "DataQualityLevel"=>1, "DateCreated"=>"2018-11-04T05:18:00Z", "SubmissionStatusTypeID"=>200, "SubmissionStatus"=>{"IsLive"=>true, "ID"=>200, "Title"=>"Submission Published"}, "UserComments"=>[{"ID"=>20389, "ChargePointID"=>112491, "CommentTypeID"=>10, "CommentType"=>{"ID"=>10, "Title"=>"General Comment"}, "UserName"=>"Robert Seemueller", "Comment"=>"Located next to the Erie Canal's \"Flight of Five\" locks, downtown shops and restaurants.", "Rating"=>5, "RelatedURL"=>nil, "DateCreated"=>"2018-11-04T05:22:02.4Z", "User"=>{"ID"=>19108, "IdentityProvider"=>nil, "Identifier"=>nil, "CurrentSessionToken"=>nil, "Username"=>"Robert Seemueller", "Profile"=>nil, "Location"=>nil, "WebsiteURL"=>nil, "ReputationPoints"=>289, "Permissions"=>nil, "PermissionsRequested"=>nil, "DateCreated"=>nil, "DateLastLogin"=>nil, "IsProfilePublic"=>nil, "IsEmergencyChargingProvider"=>nil, "IsPublicChargingProvider"=>nil, "Latitude"=>nil, "Longitude"=>nil, "EmailAddress"=>nil, "EmailHash"=>nil, "ProfileImageURL"=>"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8475a6af1852aa7fb2e1263c4ae5fac?s=80&d=mm", "IsCurrentSessionTokenValid"=>nil, "APIKey"=>nil, "SyncedSettings"=>nil}, "CheckinStatusTypeID"=>10, "CheckinStatusType"=>{"IsPositive"=>true, "IsAutomatedCheckin"=>false, "ID"=>10, "Title"=>"Charged Successfully"}}], "PercentageSimilarity"=>nil, "Connections"=>[{"ID"=>158246, "ConnectionTypeID"=>1, "ConnectionType"=>{"FormalName"=>"SAE J1772-2009", "IsDiscontinued"=>nil, "IsObsolete"=>nil, "ID"=>1, "Title"=>"J1772"}, "Reference"=>nil, "StatusTypeID"=>50, "StatusType"=>{"IsOperational"=>true, "IsUserSelectable"=>true, "ID"=>50, "Title"=>"Operational"}, "LevelID"=>2, "Level"=>{"Comments"=>"Over 2 kW, usually non-domestic socket type", "IsFastChargeCapable"=>false, "ID"=>2, "Title"=>"Level 2 : Medium (Over 2kW)"}, "Amps"=>nil, "Voltage"=>nil, "PowerKW"=>nil, "CurrentTypeID"=>nil, "CurrentType"=>nil, "Quantity"=>2, "Comments"=>nil}], "MediaItems"=>[{"ID"=>16951, "ChargePointID"=>112491, "ItemURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.orig.2018110405191125.jpg", "ItemThumbnailURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.thmb.2018110405191125.jpg", "Comment"=>"", "IsEnabled"=>true, "IsVideo"=>false, "IsFeaturedItem"=>false, "IsExternalResource"=>false, "MetadataValue"=>nil, "User"=>{"ID"=>19108, "IdentityProvider"=>nil, "Identifier"=>nil, "CurrentSessionToken"=>nil, "Username"=>"Robert Seemueller", "Profile"=>nil, "Location"=>nil, "WebsiteURL"=>nil, "ReputationPoints"=>289, "Permissions"=>nil, "PermissionsRequested"=>nil, "DateCreated"=>nil, "DateLastLogin"=>nil, "IsProfilePublic"=>nil, "IsEmergencyChargingProvider"=>nil, "IsPublicChargingProvider"=>nil, "Latitude"=>nil, "Longitude"=>nil, "EmailAddress"=>nil, "EmailHash"=>nil, "ProfileImageURL"=>"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8475a6af1852aa7fb2e1263c4ae5fac?s=80&d=mm", "IsCurrentSessionTokenValid"=>nil, "APIKey"=>nil, "SyncedSettings"=>nil}, "DateCreated"=>"2018-11-04T05:19:00Z"}, {"ID"=>16952, "ChargePointID"=>112491, "ItemURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.orig.2018110405224211.jpg", "ItemThumbnailURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.thmb.2018110405224211.jpg", "Comment"=>"", "IsEnabled"=>true, "IsVideo"=>false, "IsFeaturedItem"=>false, "IsExternalResource"=>false, "MetadataValue"=>nil, "User"=>{"ID"=>19108, "IdentityProvider"=>nil, "Identifier"=>nil, "CurrentSessionToken"=>nil, "Username"=>"Robert Seemueller", "Profile"=>nil, "Location"=>nil, "WebsiteURL"=>nil, "ReputationPoints"=>289, "Permissions"=>nil, "PermissionsRequested"=>nil, "DateCreated"=>nil, "DateLastLogin"=>nil, "IsProfilePublic"=>nil, "IsEmergencyChargingProvider"=>nil, "IsPublicChargingProvider"=>nil, "Latitude"=>nil, "Longitude"=>nil, "EmailAddress"=>nil, "EmailHash"=>nil, "ProfileImageURL"=>"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8475a6af1852aa7fb2e1263c4ae5fac?s=80&d=mm", "IsCurrentSessionTokenValid"=>nil, "APIKey"=>nil, "SyncedSettings"=>nil}, "DateCreated"=>"2018-11-04T05:23:00Z"}, {"ID"=>16953, "ChargePointID"=>112491, "ItemURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.orig.2018110405240797.jpg", "ItemThumbnailURL"=>"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/openchargemap/images/US/OCM112491/OCM-112491.thmb.2018110405240797.jpg", "Comment"=>"", "IsEnabled"=>true, "IsVideo"=>false, "IsFeaturedItem"=>false, "IsExternalResource"=>false, "MetadataValue"=>nil, "User"=>{"ID"=>19108, "IdentityProvider"=>nil, "Identifier"=>nil, "CurrentSessionToken"=>nil, "Username"=>"Robert Seemueller", "Profile"=>nil, "Location"=>nil, "WebsiteURL"=>nil, "ReputationPoints"=>289, "Permissions"=>nil, "PermissionsRequested"=>nil, "DateCreated"=>nil, "DateLastLogin"=>nil, "IsProfilePublic"=>nil, "IsEmergencyChargingProvider"=>nil, "IsPublicChargingProvider"=>nil, "Latitude"=>nil, "Longitude"=>nil, "EmailAddress"=>nil, "EmailHash"=>nil, "ProfileImageURL"=>"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8475a6af1852aa7fb2e1263c4ae5fac?s=80&d=mm", "IsCurrentSessionTokenValid"=>nil, "APIKey"=>nil, "SyncedSettings"=>nil}, "DateCreated"=>"2018-11-04T05:24:00Z"}], "MetadataValues"=>nil, "IsRecentlyVerified"=>true, "DateLastVerified"=>"2018-11-04T05:22:02.4Z"}

ChargingStations.find_sites('WA').count
 => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you use the construct `for foo in fooArray` to iterate over a Array, the `foo` is not the index but the actual item located in that position. So if you wanted your algorithm to work with minimal modifications, the "right" way would look like:

```
@@pois.each_index do |i|
  puts @@pois[i]
  // rest of the algorithm ommited
end
```

In your case, assuming that the structure of your JSON data is something like `[{lat: 10, lng: 10},{lat:5, lng:8}, {lat: 9, lng: -3]`, you are basically trying to do `@@pois[{lat: 10, lng: 5}]]`, which will give you the exact "no implicit conversion" error that you're getting. You could just use i directly like `puts i` or `i["AddressInfo"]["StateOrProvince"]` and get the right answer.

However, as it has been mentioned in the comments, a more idiomatic approach would be `@@pois.each do |poi|`. And an even **more** idiomatic approach would be to rename that ugly-looking "pois" everywhere and make it

```
@@positions.each do |position|
  puts position
  if position["AddressInfo"]["StateOrProvince"] == "New York"
    puts position
  end
end
```

Explicit variable names is the Ruby thing to do :)

And assuming the first `puts` is just a general test to see it's working and you actually want to only print the ones that are in New York...

```
@@positions.each do |position|
  puts position if position["AddressInfo"]["StateOrProvince"] == "New York"
end
```

And if you want to make that a one liner:

```
@@positions.each { |pos| puts pos if pos["AddressInfo"]["StateOrProvince"] == "New York" }
```

(yeah, I know I just talked about explicit variable names but there is no need to be too rigid about it)